# Merge 2 csv files and fill empty values from batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have to merge 2 CSV files and fill the empty columns with a default value using a batch file.

Look at the following example:

File1.csv :

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
```

File2.csv :

```
ColumnA
```

So I need to merge the ColumnA from File2 but without any duplicate so I need to check if the ColumnA value from File2 isn't on the columnA from File1 and then add it to File1.

And then when it add a Value from ColumnA File2 to ColumnA File1 I need to set values of Columns B C and D of file1 to a default value for example 'DefaultValue'.

So to summarize I need my batch code to do the following:

```
For(i = 0; i < number of row of file2.csv; i++):
   If ColumnA.value(i) isn't in File1.csv.ColumnA
      Add next row to File1.csv: ColumnA = File2.csv.ColumnA.Value(i) 
                                 ColumnB = 'DefaultValue' 
                                 ColumnC = 'DefaultValue'
                                 ColumnD = 'DefaultValue'
```

Do you have an idea how to do this using a batch file ?

Thank you

Comment: As answer to your question: Yes, I have an idea on how to do this... **`;)`**  What is the maximum number of lines in each file? Can the new rows be added in any order?

Comment: The maximum number of lines in each file is 2000 - 2500

Comment: you could do this rly easily in Python

Comment: And yes the rows can be added in any order I just need no duplicates @Aacini

Comment: You call file1 a csv, but it seems to be space separated? Iterate file2 and check with `findstr` if the current value is already present - if not append.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please read [ask] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q57065172.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q57065172_2.txt"
SET "tempfile=%destdir%\tempfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1delims= " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO %%a
)> "%tempfile%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /v /x /i /g:"%tempfile%" "%filename2%"') DO >>"%filename1%" ECHO %%a defaultB defaultC defaultD
DEL "%tempfile%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used files named `q57065172.txt` and `q57065172_2.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

`%tempfile%` is used temporarily and is a filename of your choosing.

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

Simply create a tempfile containing only the first token of each existing line. Then compare that list with the new-columnA values, and find those which are not exact matches to an existing value. For each of these (produced from `findstr`), simply append a new line to the original file with the default values for the other columns.

The column-delimiter character needs to be assigned as the `delims=?` character - I used <kbd>space</kbd>

Caution : test first on disposible data. This procedure will modify the existing `filename1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a free writing code service; you should show your own attempts to solve the problem... Anyway, here it is a very simple solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Load ColumnA from File1 into CA array
for /F %%a in (File1.csv) do set "CA[%%a]=1"

rem Process File2
(for /F %%a in (File2.csv) do (
   if not defined CA[%%a] echo %%a DefaultValueB DefaultValueC DefaultValueD
)) >> File1.csv
```